# Yii2 Dropzone,загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: php, yii2

Есть проект на Yii2, там форма с загрузкой файла, для загрузки файла использую вот это расширение [yii2-dropzone](https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone)

Ошибок в логах нет, но почему-то файлы не загружаются.

Вот вывод виджета:

```
\kato\DropZone::widget([
       'options' => [
           'maxFilesize' => '2',
           'url' => '/site/upload', // upload url
       ],
       'clientEvents' => [
           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
           'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
       ],
   ]);
```

и код в контроллере

```
    public function actionUpload(){
    $fileName = 'upFile';
    $uploadPath = '/var/www/ppms/web/site/upload';

    if (isset($_FILES[$fileName])) {
        $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);

        //Print file data
        print_r($file);

        if ($file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $file->name)) {
            //Now save file data to database

            echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($file);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в комментах к посту:
http://www.digitalaholic.com/upload-files-yii2-dropzone/

```
$csrfToken = \Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken();
echo \kato\DropZone::widget([ 
'options' => [
'url' => \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['storage/upload']) 
],
'clientEvents' => [
'sending' => "function(file, xhr, formData) { formData.append('_csrf', '{$csrfToken}'); }",
]]);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь принято давать **полный** ответ, а ссылки приводить лишь в качестве дополнения/иллюстрации.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.